# How to best judge what the quotient of two general complex numbers might be

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $w, z \in C$, shown below:

[image]

How would I determine which of $(2, -2, 2i, -2i, 1/2, -1/2, i/2, -i/2)$ is most likely to be the solution to $x=w/z$?

I think we should declare $\alpha=w/z=re^{i \theta}$ but I am not sure where to go from there.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We declare $\alpha = w/z = re^{i\theta}$ s.t $w = zre^{i\theta}$

Then $r = |\alpha|$ and $\theta$ is $Arg(\alpha)$. As we are multiplying $z$ by $\alpha$, it has stretched it by $r=|w|/|z|>1$ (clear from the diagram) and thus we can discount all of the values with a modulus less than 1.

From the diagram, we can see that $\alpha$ must rotate $z$ anti clockwise to obtain $w$ with $arg(z) \in (-\pi/2, 0)$ and $arg(w)\in(0, \pi/2)$; thus $arg(\alpha) \in (0, \pi)$ so $w/z = re^{i(arg(\alpha))}$ where $r > 1$. Therefore, the only appropriate guess for $w/z = \alpha$ is $2i$ as $arg(\alpha)$ excludes the real and negative imaginary axis.

Comment: `we know that z has been rotated` It would be more clear if you worded it something like "*$w$ can be obtained from $z$ by rotating it anticlockwise*". `w/z = r i` This is only true if you "guess" that $OW \perp OZ$ from the picture. That may be allowed, but it's stronger than necessary. It's enough to note that $\arg x \in (0,\pi)$ which excludes the real axis and the negative imaginary axis, leaving only $2i$ eligible.

Comment: I will edit to include this, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

Hint: since $|w| \gt |z|$ the modulus will be $|x| = |w|/|z|\gt 1$. Since $\arg w \in (0,\pi/2)$ and $\arg z \in (-\pi/2,0)$, $\arg x = \arg w - \arg z \in (\arg w, \arg w + \pi/2) \subseteq (0,\pi)$. There is only one number in the list which satisfies the above.

Comment: This really aided in my understanding of how to tackle this, thank you, I wanted to answer it in terms of the exponential form and have attempted it below, does it seem correct to you?